# Understanding Kirchhoff's radiation law calculation from Weinberg's book

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation

From second edition of Weinberg's *Lectures on Quantum Mechanics*,

> Consider an enclosure whose walls are kept at a temperature $T$, and suppose that the energy per volume of radiation within this enclosure in a frequency interval between $\nu$ and $\nu + d\nu$ is some function $\rho(\nu,\, T)$ times $d\nu$. Kirchoff calculated the energy per time of the radiation in any frequency interval that strikes a small patch of area $A$. He reasoned that, from a point in the enclosure with polar coordinates $r, \theta, \phi$ (with $r$ the distance to the patch, and $\theta$ measured from the normal to the patch), the patch will subtend a solid angle of $A \cos\theta / 4 \pi r^2 \times \rho(\nu, \, T) \,d\nu$ over a hemisphere with radius $ct$, where $c$ is the speed of light: $$2\pi \int_0^{ct} dr \int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta \, r^2 \sin\theta \times \frac{A \cos\theta \, \rho(\nu, T) \, d\nu}{4\pi r^2} = \frac{ctA\,\rho(\nu,\, T) \,d\nu}{4}.$$

I don't understand how are we doing the integration here. If I am correct in my understanding, the origin of our spherical coordinate system is some point in the enclosure and $\mathbf{r}$ is the vector which points to the patch from the origin. If I change $r$, then the tip of my vector $\mathbf{r}$ would not lie on the patch anymore. Similar thing for $\theta$ as well.

[image]

I know this is supposed to be trivial but I'm unable to understand it.

Edit: I think that I have a wrong idea of how is this integration being done. It would be helpful if someone could explain in detail (possibly with figures) how is the calculation done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]"He reasoned that, from a point in the enclosure with polar coordinates ,, (with  the distance to the patch, and  measured from the normal to the patch)". It means that you are integrating over all the points in the enclosure. Approximatively you can place the origin on the patch and all the possible points in the enclosure subtend the aforementioned solid angle. Hope it is clear.

Comment: "Approximatively you can place the origin on the patch and all the possible points in the enclosure subtend the aforementioned solid angle." That is what I would have thought. But Weinberg/Kirchoff does not put the origin on the patch.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't make any difference. The physics cannot depend on where you place the origin. Therefore It is equivalent if you place the origin in the enclosure or on the patch the final result is the integral over all the possible points within the enclosure radiating over an effective solid angle $Acos(\theta)/4\pi r^2$ representing the patch.

Comment: Equivalence of the integrals when my origin is kept at the patch and when my origin is at some another point is given by the experimental condition that the enclosure is in equilibrium. If it weren't in equilibrium, the integrals would be different, right?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by equilibrium. The fact is that you must sum over all the radiations Originated at each point $\bar{r}$ in the enclosure and that's it. No matter what you call Origin. To say it in another way: in the image that you're showing you're integrating over all the possible "Origins" in the enclosure

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the integration that is done here. I am modifying the question.